# No more toggle event from p:columntoggler since PF6

Tags: jsf, primefaces

we had the following snippet working perfectly in PF5.x:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="columntoggler" id="toggler" type="button" value="Toggler" icon=""/>
<p:columnToggler datasource="personTable"  trigger="toggler">
 <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{listPersonsBean.onToggleListPersons}" update=""  process="@(form)"/>
</p:columnToggler>
```

Since we switched to PF6 the listener doesn't get called anymore. Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: try to make it `onToggleListPersons()` and share with us the `onToggleListPersons` method

Comment: @YagamiLight: why _"try to make it `onToggleListPersons()`"_

Comment: i know that `onToggleListPersons()` is not linked with the version of PF but i garantie that sometimes simple solution can be the dumbest one